# How to use guild.id in tasks

Tags: discord.py

I'm attempting to create a command that runs in a loop to monitor when a server (guild) gets wiped. However, I discovered that using ctx.guild.id directly inside tasks is problematic. Is there a way to create a looping command that can access guild information without encountering this issue?

```py
@tasks.loop(seconds=120)
async def pop_status():
    for x in collection.find():
        if x["_id"] == client.get_guild(id):
            wipe = x["pop"]
    response = requests.get('https://api.battlemetrics.com/servers/' + wipe)
    pass_times = response.json()
    Server_wipe = pass_times['data']['attributes']['details']['rust_last_wipe']
    print(Server_wipe)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few options, you can pass the `guild` argument in the task when starting it, or you can get it inside the task:

```py
@tasks.loop(seconds=120)
async def pop_status(guild):
    # you can use the guild argument

# You have to pass it when starting it, example in a command
@bot.command()
async def start(ctx):
    pop_status.start(ctx.guild)
```

Getting the guild in the loop itself

```py
@tasks.loop(seconds=120)
async def pop_status():
    guild = bot.get_guild(ID_HERE)
```

*PS: You shouldn't really use the `requests` library, it's blocking, you should use [`aiohttp`](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/) instead*

Comment: Is there a way to get guild id's without putting them in manually?

Comment: You can pass the guild instance when starting the task, like in the first example

Comment: this doesn't work for me. I get this error https://pastebin.com/XmsChf0S